# Explain Error:The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins

Tags: java, android, kotlin, plugins

I will keep it simple. I am using both kotlin and java in my Android project. I can provide my gradle files if necessary.

I need the following java plugins in my project: id 'java-library'
id "org.web3j". They work on an older version of Android gradle `('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3' ; distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip)` but not on the newest one `("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1" ; distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip)` from which I need other functionality. When I try to add them I get the following error.

```
Error:The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins
```

Old gradle version has plugins:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

New gradle version has plugins:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id  'com.google.gms.google-services'
   // id "org.web3j" version "4.8.1"
  // id 'java-library'
}
```

I found others with the same problem but with no real answer. One workaround I found here is to configure them for a subproject or something, but I don't really understand how. Can somebody help? Ideally tell me what and where to put it in which gradle file and how it works (from my understanding I have only 1 project not many in my Android app).
This is the code that I found:

```
configure(allprojects) {
  println "applying java plugin to $project"
  apply plugin: 'java-library'

  //...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add org.web3j as a plugin because it contains 'java' plugins that are not compatible with 'java' plugins of android. So, you can either add 'com.android.application' plugin or 'org.web3j'. Add web3j as a dependency -
implementation ('org.web3j:core:4.8.7'). It will work fine.